# Import data in matrix-like form from text - Python

Tags: python, input, matplotlib

I have a text file, 'data.txt', which is my input file, that looks like this:

```
    X                 Y             value
5.000000e-03    5.000000e-03    0.000000e+00    
5.000000e-03    2.537500e-01    0.000000e+00    
5.000000e-03    5.025000e-01    0.000000e+00    

2.537500e-01    5.000000e-03    0.000000e+00    
2.537500e-01    2.537500e-01    3.054417e-03    
2.537500e-01    5.025000e-01    1.949042e-04    

5.025000e-01    5.000000e-03    0.000000e+00    
5.025000e-01    2.537500e-01    1.949042e-04    
5.025000e-01    5.025000e-01    3.433153e-05
```

I would like to plot this in a matrix-like form, i.e. if we call the matrix `A` we will have for example

```
A_{1 1} = 3.054417e-03
A_{1 2} = 1.949042e-04
```

and so on. How can I first of all import these data in matrix-like form, and then plot them?

Comment: try asking your favourite search engine

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy's function loadtxt:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.loadtxt('data.txt', skiprows=1, ndmin=0)
print(values)
```

Output:

```
[[  5.00000000e-03   5.00000000e-03   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.00000000e-03   2.53750000e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.00000000e-03   5.02500000e-01   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.53750000e-01   5.00000000e-03   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.53750000e-01   2.53750000e-01   3.05441700e-03]
 [  2.53750000e-01   5.02500000e-01   1.94904200e-04]
 [  5.02500000e-01   5.00000000e-03   0.00000000e+00]
 [  5.02500000e-01   2.53750000e-01   1.94904200e-04]
 [  5.02500000e-01   5.02500000e-01   3.43315300e-05]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Makc, but since this output has no commas to separate the elements, how can NummPy understand that it is a list of lists?

Comment: There is 'delimiter' in loadtxt() args, by default numpy splits values by any whitespace character, so in your case it works like a charm by default.